# Is it possible to define the increment factor for reallocations to std::vec::Vec?

Tags: rust

I have a slowly growing `std::vec::Vec`. For every reallocation of the vector when it exceeds its capacity, I want the reallocation to be done by a static number of elements.

For example, I initially allocate a vector with 1024 elements. When it reaches its capacity, I want it to be reallocated with 32 elements more and I want this parameter to be configurable.

I'm looking for a function like this:

```
Vec::new(initial_capacity, capacity_increment);
```

Where:

```
initial_capacity = 1024;
capacity_increment = 32;
```

Is this functionality available in Rust (nightly or stable)?

The docs say that you can only specify initial capacity, but it is not clear how the size is increased on every reallocation or if this parameter can ever be changed. In fact the docs say that the `Vec` is going to be a `(pointer, capacity, length)` triplet **no more and no less**.

Is there any way to have capacity increment configuration?

I need this feature because I may have a large number of elements in the vector, and every reallocation by some small amount of extra capacity is going to cause considerable delays in the processes I am running.

Comment: Can you just call [`reserve_exact`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.reserve_exact)?

Comment: "I need this feature because I may have a large number of elements in the vector, and every reallocation by some small amount of extra capacity is going to cause considerable delays in the processes I am running." ??? look like you over thinking just benchmark it after the program is finish and see if you have a bench problem. Don't over commit in prod

Comment: The actual allocation strategy used by `Vec` is to double the capacity each time, so the behaviour you described doesn't sound quire right. Did you actually measure a performance issue with repeated allocation or are you just guessing?

Comment: @PeterHall , I am trying to figure out how does it increment the capacity , and make it work like I need it. Didn't run any tests yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `Vec` (as of Rust 1.35) does not provide any mechanism to control the reallocation strategy.

When you call methods like `Vec::push`, the [current implementation of `Vec`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.35.0/src/liballoc/raw_vec.rs#L418-L430) will double the capacity when the vector is full. When you call methods like `reserve_exact`, the [current implementation of `Vec`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.35.0/src/liballoc/raw_vec.rs#L655-L658) directly uses your capacity.

> the docs say that the `Vec` is going to be a `(pointer, capacity, length)` triplet **no more and no less**.

This doesn't preclude the possibility of `Vec` being extended in a very cautious manner. For example, `Vec` is built from a `RawVec`, which is [parameterized by an allocator](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.35.0/src/liballoc/raw_vec.rs#L42-L46). So long as you use a zero-sized allocator (such as [`Global`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/struct.Global.html)), the size will still be true.

It would be *conceptually* straight-forward to have another type parameter to control the resizing behavior. That being said, it seems unlikely to occur anytime soon.

## Workarounds

If you really needed something like this, you can create a newtype around a `Vec` and call `reserve_exact` at all the appropriate points.

```
struct MyVec<T> {
    v: Vec<T>,
    increment: usize,
}

impl<T> MyVec<T> {
    fn new(capacity: usize, increment: usize) -> MyVec<T> {
        MyVec {
            v: Vec::with_capacity(capacity),
            increment,
        }
    }

    fn push(&mut self, val: T) {
        if self.v.len() == self.v.capacity() {
            self.v.reserve_exact(self.increment);
        }
        self.v.push(val);
    }
}
```

## Free advice

Don't try to optimize this until you have benchmarks that:

1. Show that this is a bottleneck
2. Can be used to prove that your "optimizations" actually make things faster

> I may have a large number of elements in the vector, and every reallocation by some small amount of extra capacity is going to cause considerable delays in the processes I am running.

I agree with this as a gut feeling, which is why your idea is so confusing to me:

> I want it to be reallocated with 32 elements more

32 elements *is* a small amount of extra capacity; by doing this it seems as if you'd be decreasing performance.

Comment: The problem with the newtype is that you have to delegate every single method, in order for it to be ergonomic - and do this check and re-allocation for quite a few more methods that just `push`. Just implementing `Deref<Target = Vec<T>>` will get you some of those methods "for free" but it has limitations too.